# google maps api v3 no labels?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to turn off all labels (street names, state names, country names etc.) from google maps using the API v3? Or are these built directly into the map images?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the [Styled Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#StyledMaps) feature of the Google Maps API v3.

Specifically, this style will disable all labels:

```
[
  {
    featureType: "all",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can apply it to a current map by using:

```
var customStyled = [];//(array shown above)
map.set('styles',customStyled);
```

Comment: Also sea and ocean names still appear. Repeat the same but with the featureType as "water" and that should also remove those water based labels.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,
you can change labels visibility property directly in css code using Styled Maps feature

or directly using the [Styled Maps Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) website

Comment: Mentioned link (Styled Maps Wizard) is broken (404).

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/gh-pages/styledmaps/wizard

Comment: Mentioned repository is broken