# Show Street Labels ON Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps. Need to know how to show street labels in javascript?  Here is the label I am talking about,

[image]

Comment: This what you are looking for? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110020/google-maps-api-v3-no-labels

Comment: @ChristopherRathermel, I got the answer. I just need to set this, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on the comment:

```
map.setOptions( { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID } );
```

please elaborate in question on what you have in mind.