# How to turn off google dollar sign marker

Tags: google-maps

I have code that interacts with Google maps.
We are showing our own markers as a round dot.
When I narrow my search to just one result and zoom in a second marker with a dollar sign embedded inside a circle appears!

How do I (in javascript) turn off Google's dollar sign embedded markers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions
and here
[google maps api v3 no labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110020/google-maps-api-v3-no-labels)

Comment: And look here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110020/google-maps-api-v3-no-labels